# Wrapping drawn image in XNA 4.0

Tags: sprite, draw, xna-4.0

[image]

As you see in the picture above, billy, our little orange dressed man, is going off the screen to the left and appearing on the right side.

This is what I want to happen, however, I can't seem to replicate this effect (I got the picture with some modifications in Paint.net).

Basically, if the players x position is negative, it should wrap to the other side. If the `x` is larger than the width, it should wrap over to the left side.

Comment: I've asked [this exact question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/how-to-create-a-2d-region-where-sprites-are-automatically-wrapped) at the gamedev section before, and got a great answer.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the solution I linked is for a general wrapping behavior in *every* direction, which is a lot more complex. If you only need horizontal wrapping, you can simplify the process *a lot*. Or you could just draw your character three times, with a screen-width offset between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw it two times when you need it.

```
 void Draw(SpriteBacth batch)
 {
      batch.Draw(Player.texture, Player.Position, player.Source, player.Color);


      if (Player.X <0)
      {
           bacth.Draw(Player.texture, Player.Position + ScreenHorizontalSize, player.Source, Player.Color);
      }
      else if (Player.X + Player.Size.Width> ScreenHorizontalSize.Width)
      {
           bacth.Draw(Player.texture, Player.Position - ScreenHorizontalSize, player.Source, Player.Color);
      }
  }

  void Update()
  {
      if (Player.X < -Player.Size.Width) Player.X += ScreenHorizontalSize.Width;
      if (Player.X > ScreenHorizontalSize.Width) Player.X -= ScreenHorizontalSize.Width;
  }
```

Of course you have to take in mind this when you check for colliding with player, you will have to check in the two positions too.